# How to make custom html controls

Tags: html, css

I have trouble creating html controls.
Do you know how to make custom dropdownlist in html?
Like create a copycat mac osx controls in a website?

Is there any standard way to do make all custom html control?

Comment: Maybe use the jQuery UI Autocomplete and make it a [comboBox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) with a MAC theme.

Answer (score 1):

*By control I take it you mean input fields*

If by **create** all you want to do is **style** ([examples here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/)) all you have to do is apply css.

If by **create** you mean **literally create your own input types** (e.g. a slider) you have to create them using JavaScript and [hidden inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

BTW, if you mean the second I suggest you look at [jQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to make my own ones!